# How to "convert" this unix command line prompt for using in Windows cmd?

Tags: unix, cmd, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Juqo.png)so I try to do this macOS tutorial to build an image classifier with tensorflow on a Windows PC, therefore the following prompt doesn't work in the Windows cmd:

```
IMAGE_SIZE=224
ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_0.50_${IMAGE_SIZE}"
python -m scripts.retrain \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --image_dir=tf_files/YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_HERE
```

The tutorial: https://medium.com/@bignikhilreddy/how-to-build-an-insanely-good-image-classifier-in-under-10-minutes-ea3edf411bc8

Hope someone can help me out...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Juqo.png)

Comment: If you have GIT installed you should have GIT Bash. Try it in there...

Comment: Please regard that this site is not a free code translation service, so you have to try it on your own! Come back here with a [mcve] of your attempts when you are facing problems and ask a specific question! Also please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set variables first

```
set IMAGE_SIZE=224
set ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_0.50_%IMAGE_SIZE%"
```

Windows uses %VAR% to get the value of a variable, equal to the ${var} in MacOS.
Run the command.

```
python -m scripts.retrain ^
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks ^
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/%ARCHITECTURE% ^
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/%ARCHITECTURE% ^
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb ^
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt ^
  --architecture=%ARCHITECTURE% ^
  --image_dir=tf_files/YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_HERE
```

Comment: The line continuation character for Windows cmd.exe is not REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash). It is a CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT (caret) (^).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me already. But now I get this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqw3t.png

Comment: @tuemerkan - You are using PowerShell and not cmd.exe. Please try with cmd.exe unless that is a requirement.

Comment: @tuemerkan please refer to the comment of lit. The answer was edited to reflect it

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi I did, this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Juqo.png

Comment: @tuemerkan Now, the python command you wanted to run successfully runs in cmd.exe. The error you are getting is a python error.

Comment: @tuemerkan - It appears that tensorflow is trying to download something over the Internet and your machine does not have access or a proxy. This is not a `cmd` problem. It might be good to remove the tags `unix`, `cmd`, and `terminal`. Or, select this answer as correct and ask a new question. If you ask a new question, paste the text into the question and do not require people to go to another site for a picture that cannot be used as text.

Comment: @tuemerkan - I am sorry that I was not clear. This question is a `cmd` question. You have selected it as the answer, so I would keep the tags. The new question is `tensorflow` and `python`.